# How do you create a 12 or 24 mnemonics code for multiple cryptocurrencies (ETH, BTC and so on..)

Tags: flutter, blockchain, cryptocurrency, mnemonics

I just started using Flutter and I am trying to create a crypto wallet app that can support multiple different cryptocurrencies. The current issue I am facing is, is that I don't know how a mnemonics code is being generated for different cryptocurrencies when trying to create a backup for multiple wallets. I am using this library btw: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bip39

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one mnemonic code for all cryptocurrencies. As you can see in the library documentation you linked, you use the mnemonic code to get a wallet seed. That wallet seed is then used to create a [HD wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet).

That single HD wallet can have many different cryptos. You differentiate between them by following the scheme in [BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki). In the accompanying [SLIP44](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md) there's a list of what HD wallet constants each currency uses.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know this. Thanks a lot for making things more clear, but is there an example I can follow on any site? I tried searching for examples, but no big results so far..

Comment: What sort of example are you looking for? There's quite a bit going on here, with entropy generation, mnemonic derivation from that entropy, seed generation from the mnemonic, and finally private key generation from the seed

Comment: I was searching for a code example online, but it seems not easy to find the right example I am looking for. Maybe it's because of the wrong search term I use on Google? Honestly, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Here's an example that should cover what you're asking for: https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s-core/tree/master/core#generating-a-bip39-mnemonic-phrase-and-an-xpriv. It's written in Scala, but should hopefully give you some pointers.

Comment: I noted that I need Bip44 to generate Ethereum wallets as well... The current library I am using doesn't support Ethereum (yet, I think): https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bitcoin_bip44#-installing-tab-

Can I use another library that takes the hex seed I generated using Bip32 and use it there to generate HD wallet for Ethereum as well? I am just not sure about the limitations. Is there a faster way to communicate with you by Discord or anything related? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I'm not familiar with addresses in Ethereum, I'm sorry.